# 01008. 00000 - "not all variables bound"

Tags: oracle

---

```
declare
.
.
.
.
begin.
.
.
  for i in (Select * from bpt_mapping_logic where master = tab_name and CHILD = 'MI9_CST_TEMP' ) loop

          str1 := i.all_cols;
          str2 := i.default_val;

          select 'insert into '||i.child||'_temp 
          ('||str1||' )
          values 
          (' ||str2||' )' into str3 from dual;

          select i.mapping into str5 from dual;    

          dbms_output.put_line (str3);
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STR3;

end loop;

end;
```

---

for above code im getting 
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound" error

dbms output for str3 ::::::::

```
str3 =  

insert into  
MI9_CST_TEMP_temp (  A , B , C , D )
values
('aaa'  , 'bbb' , &C . &D);
```

it is showing

1. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
   *Cause:

error during execute

Comment: You're using variables `&C` and `&D` in your `INSERT` - where did you define them / assign values to them ?

Comment: Your code is partial. You have colon (:) or ampersand(&) in your query string? Then ofcourse EXECUTE IMMEDIATE will throw an error. make sure, the string you generate is syntactically valid, if at all you define some variable , try EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... USING ..

Answer (score 0):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` cannot access SQL*PLUS variables that way; if you know there will be exactly two host variables, which will be named &C and &D, you can try

```
str3 := replace(replace(str3, chr(38)||'C', ':1'), chr(38)||'D', ':2');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STR3 using '&C', '&D';
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.


can I use


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STR3 using strx;


(strx := &c, &d )

Comment: In the USING clause, you need one argument for each `:n` placeholder of the statement. Therefore, I fear the answer is "no".